# Why javascript only runs on the first record and not in others

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a problem, i recovered data from a file using a foreach to the data in each row show a button to edit, that calls a modal window in the window that  select a type of criteria and the corresponding inputs are shown, the problem is that in the first row only does and not in others.

part of the code:

```js
 if (sel2.value == "actual") {
  document.getElementById("divactual").style.display = "block";
  divT=document.getElementById("divnuevo");
  divT.style.display = "none";
 }
 if(sel2.value == "nuevo"){
  document.getElementById("divnuevo").style.display = "block";
  divT=document.getElementById("divactual");
  divT.style.display = "none";
 }
 if(sel2.value == "vacio"){
  document.getElementById("divnuevo").style.display = "none";
  divT=document.getElementById("divactual");
  divT.style.display = "none";  
 }
}
```

```css
#divnuevo, #divactual{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
                         <table class="table table-list-search table-striped table-bordered text-table">
                            <thead>
          <tr>
           <th class="text-center">Tipo de Regla</th>
           <th class="text-center">Nombre Campo</th>
           <th class="text-center">Nombre Regla</th>
           <th class="text-center">Pos Ini</th>
           <th class="text-center">Pos Fin</th>
           <th class="text-center">Token</th>
           <th class="text-center">Criterio</th>
           <th class="text-center">Argumentos</th>
           <th class="text-center">Descripción</th>
           <th></th>                
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          <c:choose>
              <c:when test="${generals.size()==0}">
                 <td colspan="11"><h3 class="text-danger">No existen Registros de Reglas Generales en el Archivo</h3> </td>
                  <br/>
              </c:when>    
             <c:otherwise>
            <c:forEach items="${generals}" var="generals">
                <tr>
              <td>${generals.tipoRegla}</td>
                <td>${generals.nomCampo}</td>
                <td>${generals.nomRegla}</td>
                <td>${generals.posIni}</td>
              <td>${generals.posFin}</td>
              <td>${generals.token}</td>
              <td class="wrap"><p class="test"> ${generals.criterio} </p> </td>                        
              <td class="wrap"><p class="test2">${generals.argumentos} </p> </td>
              <td class="wrap"><p class="test"> ${generals.descrip} </p> </td>
              <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${generals.nomRegla}"/>
              <td>               
               <a role="button" 
                data-target="#Modificar_${generals.token }_${generals.tipoRegla}_${generals.nomCampo}_${generals.nomRegla}_${generals.posIni}_${generals.posFin}_${generals.criterio}"  
                class="btn btn-default modify" data-toggle="modal">
                <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o white"></span>
               </a>
               <form action="deletegeneral" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" value="${nombreArchivoReglas}" name="nombreArchivo" />
                <input type="hidden" value="${generals.nomRegla}" name="dnomRegla">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default delete" onclick="showAlert('&iquest;Est&aacute; seguro que desea eliminar la regla \n &#34; ${generals.nomRegla} &#34;?',3);">
                 <span class="fa fa-trash-o white"></span></button>
               </form>
               <!--button type="button" class="btn btn-default modify" data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#Modificar2"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o white"></span></button-->
              </td>
             </tr>
              <!--Para Modal de Modificacion-->
             <div class="modal fade" id="Modificar_${generals.token}_${generals.tipoRegla}_${generals.nomCampo}_${generals.nomRegla}_${generals.posIni}_${generals.posFin}_${generals.criterio}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                 </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modificar Regla</h4>
                </div>
                   <!-- Modal Body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                 <form action="actualizargenerals" method="POST">
                  <input type="hidden" value="${nombreArchivoReglas}" name="nombreArchivo" >
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tipo Regla</label>
                  <input type='text' name='tipoRegla' class='form-control' id='nomCampo' readonly="readonly" placeholder=Tipo de Regla" value="${generals.tipoRegla}" required>      
                                     
                         
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Campo</label> 
                  <input type='text' name='nombreCampo' class='form-control' id='nomCampo' placeholder="Nombre del Campo" value="${generals.nomCampo}" required>
                      
                     
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Regla</label> 
                  <input type='text' name='nombreRegla' readonly="readonly" class='form-control' id='nombreRegla' placeholder="Nombre de la Regla" value="${generals.nomRegla}" required /> 
                     
                     
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Inicio</label> 
                  <input type='number' name='posIni' class='form-control' id='posInicial'  placeholder="Posición Inicial" value="${generals.posIni}" required min="0" max="254" />
                     
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Fin</label> 
                  <input type='number' name='posFin' class='form-control' id='posFinal' placeholder="Posición Final" value="${generals.posFin}" min="0" max="254" required>
                                    
                  <c:choose>
                   <c:when test="${generals.tipoRegla eq 'TOKEN' }">
                    <label for="token">Token</label> 
                    <input type='text' name='token' class='form-control' id='token' value="${generals.token}"  placeholder="Token">
                   </c:when>
                  </c:choose>
                                     
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Argumentos</label>
                  <div class="row">
                  
                   <select class="form-control" name="tipocriterio" onchange="changeFunc4(this);" >
                    <option selected value="vacio" >----------</option>
                    <option value="actual" >ACTUAL</option>   
                    <option value="nuevo" >NUEVO</option>                    
                   </select>
                   
                   <div id="divactual"  name="divactual">
                     div actul no mostrara mas que el valor actual
                   </div>
                     
                   <div id="divnuevo"  name="divnuevo">
                     div nuevo tendra mas elementos
                   </div>
                  </div>
                        
                   <!-- Modal Footer -->
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                     <button href="#" class="btn btnAceptar">Modificar Regla</button>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btnCancelar" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                 </form>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
                         
              <!--Finaliza Modal de modifacion-->               
            </c:forEach>
           </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
         </tbody>
        </table>
```

ideas?

Comment: You have table rows <tr> which are not enclosed in a table element when you start adding divs. This is not well-formed html.

Comment: ok, i put the full code.

Comment: This still shows you placing your modal(s) in the middle of your table. Your code will basically end up <table><tr></tr><div></div><tr></tr><div></div></table> You should not have those divs inside the table.

Comment: Create a seperate foreach loop below the table and move the modal code into that so it is outside the table tags.

Comment: Modal is within the foreach because it is the way I found to pass the modal parameters in spring- mvc. How pass parameter to Modal in spring-mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of placing the code below the closing table tag.

```
</table>
<c:if test="${generals.size()!=0}">
    <c:forEach items="${generals}" var="generals">
        <!--Para Modal de Modificacion-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="Modificar_${generals.token}_${generals.tipoRegla}_${generals.nomCampo}_${generals.nomRegla}_${generals.posIni}_${generals.posFin}_${generals.criterio}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modificar Regla</h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="actualizargenerals" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" value="${nombreArchivoReglas}" name="nombreArchivo" >
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tipo Regla</label>
                            <input  type='text' name='tipoRegla' class='form-control' id='nomCampo' readonly="readonly" placeholder=Tipo de Regla" value="${generals.tipoRegla}" required>


                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Campo</label>
                            <input  type='text' name='nombreCampo' class='form-control' id='nomCampo' placeholder="Nombre del Campo" value="${generals.nomCampo}" required>


                            <label  for="exampleInputPassword1">Regla</label>
                            <input type='text' name='nombreRegla' readonly="readonly" class='form-control' id='nombreRegla' placeholder="Nombre de la Regla" value="${generals.nomRegla}" required />


                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Inicio</label>
                            <input type='number' name='posIni' class='form-control' id='posInicial'  placeholder="Posición Inicial" value="${generals.posIni}" required min="0" max="254" />

                            <label  for="exampleInputPassword1">Fin</label>
                            <input type='number' name='posFin' class='form-control' id='posFinal' placeholder="Posición Final" value="${generals.posFin}" min="0" max="254" required>

                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${generals.tipoRegla eq 'TOKEN' }">
                                    <label for="token">Token</label>
                                    <input type='text' name='token' class='form-control' id='token' value="${generals.token}"  placeholder="Token">
                                </c:when>
                            </c:choose>

                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Argumentos</label>
                            <div class="row">

                                <select class="form-control" name="tipocriterio" onchange="changeFunc4(this);" >
                                    <option selected value="vacio" >----------</option>
                                    <option value="actual" >ACTUAL</option>
                                    <option value="nuevo" >NUEVO</option>
                                </select>

                                <div id="divactual"  name="divactual">
                                    div actul no mostrara mas que el valor actual
                                </div>

                                <div id="divnuevo"  name="divnuevo">
                                    div nuevo tendra mas elementos
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Modal Footer -->
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                                        <button href="#" class="btn btnAceptar">Modificar Regla</button>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btnCancelar" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Finaliza Modal de modifacion-->
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

So just move the modal code and leave the rest as is.

EDIT:

Here is an example of your changeFunc4 function written in jQuery to target just the elements next to the current select box:

```
function changeFunc4(sel2){
var sel = $(sel2);
if (sel.val() == "actual") {
        sel.siblings( ".divactual" ).show();
        sel.siblings( ".divnuevo" ).hide();
    }
    if(sel.val() ==  "nuevo"){
        sel.siblings( ".divnuevo" ).show();
        sel.siblings( ".divactual" ).hide();
    }
    if(sel.val() == "vacio"){
        sel.siblings( ".divnuevo" ).hide();
        sel.siblings( ".divactual" ).hide();    
    }
}
```

Note, this uses css class reference so you need to update your divs to include a class. e.g.

```
<div id="divactual" class="divactual"  name="divactual">
    div actul no mostrara mas que el valor actual
 </div>
```

Comment: right, thanks, but only works in the first row and not in the others?.
to hide and show elements divs. 
<select class="form-control" name="tipocriterio" onchange="changeFunc4(this);" >
.......

Comment: This is probably because you are using the same id for multiple instances of divactual and divnevo. You need to make the ids unique. Or you could swap to using a class to display the one closest to the current select box.

Comment: Hi, It would be valid generate random names and use to name the divs?